# subset xts object if one column meets some criteria within same day

Tags: r, xts

I would like to exclude those days when `x2` equals zero more than a predetermined number of times (i.e. > 300 during the same day):

```
library(xts)
set.seed(1)
tmp <- seq(as.POSIXct('2013-09-03 00:00:01'),
           as.POSIXct('2013-09-06 23:59:59'), by='min')
x1 <- rnorm(length(tmp))
x2 <- rnorm(length(tmp))
x2 [1:400] <- 0

x <- xts(cbind(x1, x2), tmp)
```

I've found `.indexday` function to subset within days so one possibility is to write a for loop that subsets by day and calculates the number of elements on `x2`that are equal to zero but I'm sure that there is a more efficient way of doing it.

The output would be the same object `x` without those days in which there are more than 300 cases with `x2 == 0`.

Comment: Your question does not fit the StackOverflow model (it is not a Mechanical Turk). See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the [StackOverflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810).

Comment: @Joshua Ulrich I was trying to be specific but I'm sorry if it wasn't clear. I have edited my question.

Comment: The problem isn't that you were too specific. It's that you didn't show what you tried or what the output should be. Showing what you tried is important because it demonstrates that you understand we're not here to do your work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
##split idx object with respect to days
aa <- split.xts(x, f="days")

## get indices of days for which x2 == 0 less than 300 times
idx <- which(lapply(aa, function(xx){length(which(xx[,"x2"]==0))}) <= 300)

idx
[1] 2 3 4

##make one xts object containing only the desired days
new.x <- do.call(rbind, aa[idx])

dim(x)
[1] 5760    2

dim(new.x)
[1] 4320    2
```

Answer (score 2):

Whatever solution you use, you need to be careful with timezones when converting from POSIXt to Date.  Here's a solution using `ave`:

```
> x <- xts(cbind(x1, x2), tmp, tzone="UTC")
> y <- x[ave(x$x2==0, as.Date(index(x)), FUN=sum) < 300,]
> head(y)
                            x1         x2
2013-09-04 00:00:01  0.6855122  0.8171146
2013-09-04 00:01:01  0.3895035  0.1818066
2013-09-04 00:02:01 -1.3053959  1.2532384
2013-09-04 00:03:01  1.2168880  0.6069871
2013-09-04 00:04:01  0.7951740  0.2825354
2013-09-04 00:05:01 -0.4882025 -0.3089424
```

Comment: thanks for that solution. I must be doing something wrong because I tried `tzone=Sys.timezone()` but can't subset`y`.

Comment: `Sys.timezone()` isn't guaranteed to return anything useful, since it's OS-specific, as it says in `?Sys.timezone`.  It's better to get/set the `TZ` environment variable.